# F# strange printfn problem

Tags: f#

I was playing around with F# (Visual Studio 2010 beta 1), and I wrote a little console script that asked the user to input 2 numbers and an operator and then executed it.
It works fine, apart from a tiny, but annoying thing: sometimes my printfn instructions are ignored. I placed breakpoints in the code to see that's indeed the case.

The code snippet:

```
let convert (source : string) =
    try System.Int32.Parse(source)
    with :? System.FormatException ->
        printfn "'%s' is not a number!" source;
        waitForExitKey();
        exit 1

let read =
    printfn "Please enter a number.";
    System.Console.ReadLine

let num1 : int = read() |> convert // the printfn in the read function is run...
let num2 : int = read() |> convert // ... but here is ignored
```

This is not the complete source of course, but I think that'll be enough. If you need the complete source just let me know.

So my question is pretty simple: what causes this issue with printfn? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,
ShdNx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching) has a partial explanation of what's going on, but the short and sweet version is that F# will execute any value on declaration if it doesn't take parameters.

```
let read =
    printfn "Please enter a number."
    System.Console.ReadLine
```

Since `read` doesn't take any parameters, its executed immediately on declaration and binds the return value of the function to the identifier `read`.

Incidentally, your return value happens to be a function with the type `(unit -> string)`. This results because F# automatically [curries functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions#Currying_and_Partial_Functions) if they aren't passed all of their parameters. `ReadLine` expects one unit parameter, but since it isn't passed on, you actually bind `read` to the `ReadLine` function itself.

The solution is as follows:

```
let read() = // read takes one unit parameter
    printfn "Please enter a number."
    System.Console.ReadLine() // pass paramter to ReadLine method
```

Since `read` takes one parameter, its re-evaluated each time its called. Additionally, we're passing a parameter to `ReadLine`, otherwise we'll just return the `ReadLine` function as a value.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately Ray was faster, so I accepted his answer. But I'm still very glad you made this clear. Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

I understand that this can be confusing. In your example, `printfn` runs earlier than you think. It will actually execute even without the call to `read()`, i.e., comment out the last two lines and you will still see a message being printed.

I think your intention is something like this:

```
let read() =
    printfn "Please enter a number.";
    System.Console.ReadLine()
```

This will create a "reusable" function instead of binding a function to an identifier as in your original example.

As a sidenote, the use of semi-colons here is optional so you can just write:

```
let read() =
    printfn "Please enter a number."
    System.Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand it now!
I use semi-colons because I automatically add a semicolon after each line and it bothers me if I can't see any... :-)